# Evaluating my model in new unseen dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have trained my model (`.fit()`) and satisfied with the performance on test split making prediction (`.predict()`). So I save my model to the disk (`.save('model.h5')`).

Now I'm given new unseen dataset and asked to evaluate my already saved model on this dataset for performance. I am required to not only report accuracy but stuff line precision/recall, confusion matrix etc...

I then loaded my saved model (`.load_model('model.h5')`).

**Question:**
What the appropriate function that I should use to prepare report of the model performance on this new dataset. I should I use `.predict()` function or `.evaluate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sklearn's classification_report to generate all the relevant metrics.
**Code:**

```
preds = model.predict(x1)
y_pred = np.argmax(preds, axis = 1)
print(classification_report(y1, y_pred))
```

**Output:**

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.71      0.08      0.15        59
           1       0.42      0.95      0.58        41

    accuracy                           0.44       100
   macro avg       0.57      0.52      0.37       100
weighted avg       0.59      0.44      0.33       100
```

You can see all available metrics [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#:%7E:text=The%20sklearn.,values%2C%20or%20binary%20decisions%20values.).

**model.evaluate() :**
This method will provide the values for loss and metrics you defined in your compile method which is generally not enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get loss/accuracy or whatever other metrics you had during training - you need  `.evaluate()` method. If all you need is actual probabilities or regression values - you need `.predict()` method.